# Convergence of the relative difference of a sequence to the power of $\gamma$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A book states for $\gamma \in (0.5,1]$ we have

$$
\frac{n^{-\gamma} - (n+1)^{-\gamma}}{n^{-\gamma}}\in O(1/n)
$$

For $\gamma = 1$ this is relatively easy:

$$
\frac{1/n - 1/(n+1)}{1/n} = 1- \frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}
$$

But I can not figure out the proof for the more general statement. I tried L'Hopital but that does not seem to result in something useful. I am not even sure if this is true anymore

Comment: You can use the binomial series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {n^{-\gamma} -(n+1)^{-\gamma}} {n^{-\gamma}}=1-(1+\frac  1 n)^{-\gamma}$. Now $(1+\frac  1 n)^{-\gamma}$ lies between $(1+\frac  1 n)^{-\frac 1 2 }$ and $(1+\frac  1 n)^{-1}$. Can you show  that $n(1-(1+\frac  1 n)^{-\frac 1 2 })$ and $n(1-(1+\frac  1 n)^{-1  }$) are both bounded?

[L'Hopital's Rule gives $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-(1+x)^{t}} x \to -t$ for any $t $. Put $x=\frac  1 n$. Take $t=-1$ and then $t=-\frac  1 2$].

Comment: $t=1,1/2$ does not really correspond to $\gamma =1,1/2$ due to the minus in front of the gamma. But I am also not sure why you think that $t>0$ is necessary.  Which then would be a solution. I shouldn't have looked at $x\to\infty$ in L'Hopital with $1/x$ everywhere I guess :facepalm:

Comment: @Felix B. Fixed.